# Recursive function stop processing a conditional branch

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I have a function `can_obtain` to proof if a string `init` can be transformed to string `target` with the the following conditions:

- string `init` and `target` only consist of letter "X" and/or "Y" (like "XY", "XXX", "YYXY", "Y", etc.)
- string `target` is longer than `init`
- options to get to `target` are

  - concatenate "X" to `init` or
  - reverse and concatenate "Y" to `init`

Here is the function, with trivial operations such as `contains` and `reverse` removed for terseness.

```
let can_obtain init target = 
  let final = 
    let rec reduce i text =
      if i >= String.length target then text
      else 
        let next = 
          let branchX = text ^ "X" in
          let branchY = (reverse text) ^ "Y" in
          if contains target branchX then branchX
          else if contains target branchY then branchY
          else text
        in 
          reduce (i+1) next
     in
       reduce (String.length init) init
   in
     final = target
;;
```

Problem is with these transitions it returns `true`, which is correct

```
(* concat "X" only *)
(* "XY" -> "XYX" -> "XYXX" *)
can_obtain "XY" "XYXX";;

(* reverse and concat "Y" only *)
(* "XY" -> "YXY" -> "YXYY" -> "YXYYY" *)
can_obtain "XY" "YXYYY";;

(* reverse and concat "Y", then concat "X" lastly *)
(* "XY" -> "YXY" -> "YXYY" -> "YYXYY" -> "YYXYYX" *)
can_obtain "XY" "YYXYYX";;
```

However, if at some point in the transition "X" is concatenated, the function would refuse to switch to the reverse branch and just return `false`:

```
(* concat "X", then tries to reverse then concat "Y" *)
(* "XY" -> "XYX" -> "XYXY" *)
can_obtain "XY" "XYXY";;  (* false *)
```

I know I'm missing just a small piece here, and the code looks really messy too. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Your code is not a valid OCaml program.

Comment: Where did I get it wrong? @camlspotter

Comment: at least capital letters for args...

Comment: @PierreG. I don't think that makes it invalid, maybe just ugly. Edited though.

Comment: Starting by a capital letter is restricted to constructors : type t1 = Int of (int, string);; Int is a constructor. See https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/data_types_and_matching.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`can_obtain` is a recursive function - so let's define the stop conditions first :

stop conditions:

- if n=i then this is a success
- if length i > length n then failure

If stop conditions are not met, then we have to go further and try with the 2 hypothesis : `(init ^ "X")`, `((reverse init) ^ "Y")`

So the code results in :

```
let rec can_obtain init target = 
  if init = target then
    true
  else if String.length init >= String.length target then
    false 
  else
    (can_obtain (init ^ "X") target) || (can_obtain ((reverse init) ^ "Y") target)
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `can_obtain`? Also, this part `if i >= String.length target then text` was already a base case to stop recursion, was it?

Comment: if i >= String.length ... is a base to stop recursion : yes, correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at your code the obvious problem is that N might contain both branchX and branchY. In that case (it seems to me) you want to pursue both possibilities, but you're pursuing only the first.

**Update**

Another observation is that you probably want to pursue a branch if N contains the branch or its reverse. One of your operations reverses the string, and this operation might be applied an odd number of times for all you know.

Comment: The brute force way would be to use backtracking. When further progress is impossible, you return a failure indication. When you see failure pursuing the branchX possibility you want see if the branchY possibility works.